# Why does submit refresh page

Tags: html, submit

I found innumerable answers and explanations on refreshing after submit - how to do it, how to prevent it, etc. But I'm just wondering why all submit functions automatically reload the page? I would have thought the default is to not refresh, and there's an option for it, something like

```
<button type="submit" refresh="false">Submit</button>
```

Is this like an unspoken programming rule, or is there a reason to do with `GET` and `POST` requests or something of that kind?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form is like clicking a link.

1. You send something to the server (when you click a link that's just a URL, with a form it is more complex data).
2. The server makes a response
3. The browser shows you the response

It would only "reload the page" if the server side code you wrote sent the same page back.

---

It's the normal behaviour because when you send data to the server, you usually want to know if it worked.

(The server could response with `204 No Content` to avoid the browser loading a new page, but that would confuse most users because they would have clicked a button and nothing would appear to happen).

Comment: What about if the response isn't actually being displayed? It still reloads the page ...?

Comment: @Still_learning — If it is "reloading the page" then it *is* displaying the resource. It's just the resource the server responded with is the same page.

Comment: Then is the refresh a result of displaying new data? If yes, how can it be that I can display new data without refreshing? (Btw I'm working in Vue, that might explain my confusion)

Comment: If you want to display new data without reloading the page, the you need to use JavaScript. Register an event handler on the form that listens for the submit event, prevents the default behaviour, collects the data, sends it via Ajax, waits for the data to come back, and then insert the data from the response into the DOM with JS.

Comment: In Vue, `v-on:submit.prevent="methodCall()"` does the same thing as `v-on:submit="methodCall()"` - only difference is the page reload. So what is the point of the submit button automatically refreshing the page? What does it help?

Comment: @Still_learning — Sometimes you want to run some JS and then do a normal form submission. Sometimes you want to run some JS *instead* of a normal form submission. Pick whichever one suits the problem you are trying to solve.